# How to round to a speicific number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, rounding, nested-if

I assume this may be an easy task, I have tried searching in the community, but can't find the one which I am looking for, so i have some numbers and want to round to a specific number,

| BEFORE | AFTER ROUNDED |
| --- | --- |
| 431 | 435 |
| 432 | 435 |
| 433 | 435 |
| 434 | 435 |
| 435 | 435 |
| 430 | 429 |
| 436 | 439 |
| 437 | 439 |
| 438 | 439 |
| 439 | 439 |
| 440 | 439 |

So, if the last digit is between 1-5 it will be i.e. 432 becomes 435; while 437 becomes 439. Also a sample data shown above, i have tried using MROUND or FLOOR Function but not getting through it, any way to get around this

Comment: No, not just these two values, but, like if its 336 it will become 339 while if its 530 it becomes 529, i,e 1-5 will be 5 while 6-9 & 0 will be 9, sorry i am not able to explain it

Comment: Still its not working, i have changed `A1:A11` to `X9:X14`

Comment: can you share a copy / sample of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 let me create one, its on my work laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(INT(X9:X14)&""; ".+[1-5]$"); REGEXEXTRACT(INT(X9:X14)&""; "(.*)\d$")&5; 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(INT(X9:X14)&""; ".+[0]$"); INT(X9:X14)-1; REGEXEXTRACT(INT(X9:X14)&""; "(.*)\d$")&9))*1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a little tricky.I worked mostly with `rounddown`. I started by getting the ones number, i.e., whether we are 6-9&0 or 1-5.

> A1-rounddown(A1,-1)

[image]

I then moved to find which number to replace it with using an `ifs` to get all the cases.

> =IFS(B1=0,9,B1<=5,5,A1-B1>5,9)

Afterwards I ran another `ifs` clause for the 3 cases where <>0, <=5, >5. I finally combined everything into a one-liner:

`=if(A1-rounddown(A1,-1)<>0,rounddown(A1,-1)+IFS(A1-rounddown(A1,-1)=0,9,A1-rounddown(A1,-1)<=5,5,A1-rounddown(A1,-1)>5,9),A1-1)`

Hopefully this was understandable and helpful.

Comment: Not worked 370 needs to be 369 but its rounding to 375

Comment: Ok, this is weird I just tried this:
=if(A11-rounddown(A11,-1)<>0,rounddown(A11,-1)+IFS(A11-rounddown(A11,-1)=0,9,A11-rounddown(A11,-1)<=5,5,A11-rounddown(A11,-1)>5,9),A11-1) on my computer and it worked

Comment: see i have edited

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I was entering integers while you had decimals. When I enter `V12+W12` it gets the wrong number, if you round the X column to an integer I believe it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

- Round to nearest 5
- If (number - 1) mod 10 > 4 (i.e. 6, 7, 8, 9), subtract 1 to get 9
- Otherwise, leave it alone to not round

```
=ArrayFormula(CEILING(A:A/5)*5-(MOD(A:A-1,10)>4))
```